# Kotlin: Generic high-order function - Type mismatch

Tags: kotlin, generics, types

I'm trying to grasp generics in Kotlin.

In the following sample, I'm trying to constrain the type `T` and use it inside a high-order function, or just functions in general.

```kotlin
interface A {
    fun foo()
}

class bar<T : A> (val g: A, val h: T, val callable: (T) -> Unit ) {
    fun test() {
        // Polymorphism works as expected
        g.foo()
        h.foo()

        // Type mismatch: inferred type is A but T was expected
        callable(g)

        // Fine
        callable(h)
        
        // Type mismatch: inferred type is A but T was expected
        baz(g)

        // Fine
        baz(h)
    }
    
    fun baz(l: T) {}
}
```

Could you please explain why it doesn't compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared that `T` must be a supertype of `A`.

Let's use a more graphic example.
Assume `A` is a `Person` and `T` is a `Teacher`. You've declared that a `Teacher` is a `Person` - which makes sense. However, the opposite is not true. Not all `Person`s (`A`) are `Teacher`s (`T`).

When invoking both `bar` and `callable` you expect a `Teacher` to be passed in.

You cannot simply call these functions with a `Person` or `A`, because that person might not be a `Teacher` (or `T`).